# Which is better w.r.t battery usage ? Having bluetooth always on OR switching it on/off intermittently ?

Tags: android, bluetooth, battery

I'm writing a app that requires bluetooth. I periodically check if I need to synchronize some data.
W.r.t battery usage which is better ?

- Having bluetooth always on and using it when needed for communication.
  OR
- Switching it on when needed and switching it off.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you shouldn't force the BT state on the users, for whatever reasons they might prefer to keep it on or off. The only thing you application can do is to ask the user to switch BT on whenever you need it (using intent BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE), and if you ask every 30mn or so it is rapidly going to be annoying.

Remember the enable() method in BluetoothAdapter should not be used without user consent (from sdk reference):

> Bluetooth should never be enabled without direct user consent. If you want to turn on Bluetooth in order to create a wireless connection, you should use the ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE Intent, which will raise a dialog that requests user permission to turn on Bluetooth. The enable() method is provided only for applications that include a user interface for changing system settings, such as a "power manager" app.

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on the time interval between your checks. If the checks are at large intervals, it's better to switch on/off, otherwise, if they are often it probably won't make much difference to keep in on.

Comment: typical interval is once in 30 mins

Comment: Then it seems that it's probably better to just switch on/off. You should look over a power consumption chart, but I think that keeping BT on for 30 mins will drain too much battery.

Answer (score 0):

Add a button to "turn on bluetooth and sync", when it's over give the user feedback and then request to turn it off.